# Precompiled SQLite binaries for Windows x64

Tags: windows, sqlite, 64-bit, precompiled-binaries

Are there precompiled binaries for Windows 64bit of SQLite?
So far I was unable to find such

Thanks.

Comment: You would find the latest SQLite3 dll for Win64 at http://sourceforge.net/projects/cyqlite/files/?source=navbar

Answer (score 2):

http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/downloads.wiki

Comment: That is a different project, derived from SQLite and not the basic SQLite. It says of itself "System.Data.SQLite is an ADO.NET provider for SQLite." I don't think it has the basic SQLite binaries.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/files/beta/autoit/archive/sqlite/

I downloaded the DLL files of the latest version, both of x86 & x64. It works. :)

Compare with the official x86 version from SQLite.org, it includes an extra function called SQLite_version.