# Precompiled SQLite x64 without .net

Tags: c++, visual-studio, sqlite, 64-bit

I needed SQLite for Win x64 to use in the C++ project in MS VS 2010. And I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4315606/precompiled-sqlite-binaries-for-windows-x64) with the link to x64 build, but it needs .net framework. Can I use in the my project? Also, I am about to use automated building on server side in this project, so it can be a problem to meet additional requirements (does it?).

So, does anyone have a link to precompiled SQLite DLL for x64 or I need to build it from sources? Also, if I am wrong about .net version and it is the one I need, let me know, please.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no official precompiled 64-bit Windows DLL of SQLite.

However, compiling it yourself is trivial: just [download](http://www.sqlite.org/download.html) the amalgamation and add the .c file to your project; there are no additional configuration steps or requirements.

Comment: Thanks, it is so obvious that I didn't noticed, the best and the simplest solution!

Answer (score 4):

If you do not wish to link the library statically (or compile it directly into your application as suggested in the only answer available here so far), you can use the [short tutorial I created recently](http://pavel.cernohorsky.name/blog/2015/09/sqlite_64-bit_binaries_for_windows_and_how_to_build_them_with_visual_studio_2015.php). The binaries are available there as well if you need them. It uses MS VS 2015. A long time passed since your original question, but maybe someone else can find this useful.

Edit: As somebody stated below, simply providing the link is not enough, so just briefly the basics of the tutorial: You have to download the amalgamation source code from the original SQLite page and you can compile dll from it in your visual studio, but crucial is to set proper pre-processor directives for the compiler:

```
SQLITE_ENABLE_FTS4=1
SQLITE_ENABLE_RTREE=1
SQLITE_ENABLE_COLUMN_METADATA=1
SQLITE_API=__declspec(dllexport)
```

Especially last one is the one which makes your library usable. This information is not mentioned in the original instructions for building the library from the sources using the Microsoft toolchain.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. See [How do I write a good answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thanks for reminding me, but I afraid that without actually copy+pasting the tutorial here, there is no chance how to explain the whole thing in just a few characters, especially when the original question stated "does anyone have a link to..", so I simply answered the original question... Anyway - I will add some more details to my answer.

Comment: Pavel, very helpful answer.  Thank you.